# jquery attr use variable?

Tags: jquery

Are you able to place a variable into attr of src?

Example:

```
$("#member-image2").attr({src : image});
```

I am using facebook connect and the "image" is their variable and "member-image2" is my img ID ..

Is this even possible? Because as is, it is not doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
$("#member-image2").attr({src : ''+image+''});
```

Had to just trick to be a string..

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, but what does the image var say if you alert or log it ?

Is it a valid url ?